# What pre-emergent weed killers won't harm my 'Blue Rug' juniper?

Tags: weed-control, ground-cover

I have some weeds that keep coming back in my 'blue rug' junipers. I reasearched it a little and found that pre-emergent weed killers are practical, but I am not sure which ones are safe to use on 'blue rug'. Please enlighten me concerning what is safe and what is not when it comes to 'blue rug' and pre-emergent weed killer.

Comment: What kind of weeds?  Grasses,dandelions,vetch?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, I use [oryzalin,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oryzalin) [benfluralin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benfluralin), or [dithiopyr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithiopyr) based pre-emergent herbicides. Use according to the instructions on the product label, and be aware of possible contamination of groundwater.

Answer (score -1):

Pre-emergents do not affect existing plantings. They do prevent seeds from germinating.  Hence, they would prevent annual grasses from eating your Junipers alive.  I use Preen for this purpose.

It is a also very effective against the rapacious annual Japanese stilt grass, which is a noxious invasive exotic weed afflicting the Southeast.

Comment: pre-emergents prevent seed germination. They are not toxic to existing plants.

Comment: Yeah I don't see what question you are answering with "No", I want to up vote the preen bit.